# Unable to copy a smaller array into a larger pre-filled array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to copy a list of words, each separated by a newline, into a new array of size 16, whose values are all hex versions of the pound character '#'. Since, these words may be less than 16, the final value for word should be the word itself, and the remaining positions as the '#' character, which do not get replaced from the original array. The code for it as follows:

```
     fp = fopen("english_words.txt", "r");

        if (fp != NULL) {   
            while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {

                if (read < 16) {


                    unsigned char word[16] = {0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23};
//read -1 and not read to ignore the last \n character in line
                    for (int i = 0; i < read - 1; i++) {
                        word[i] = line[i];
                        printf("%x", word[i]);

                    }



                    }
                    printf("\n");   


        }
        fclose(fp);
        if (line)
            free(line);


}
```

However, when I print the final output, it seems like the final array for each word does not seem to have any pound characters left at all. Could anyone help with this?

EDIT:

Sample Input with file containing the following words, each separated by a newline:

```
abacus
abalone
abandon

Output:
abacus##########
abalone#########
abandon#########
```

I am going to handle each of these outputted words separately, so do not need to put them on a file.

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: Also (though I don't know if it could happen), you might want to consider what happens if `getline` return `0`.

Comment: added in the question

Comment: Lastly, the best way to solve such problems is to [debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `"//read -1 and not read to ignore the last \n character in line"` -- **note:** not all files contain a POSIX line end on the final line. You can use `line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;` to cover all cases.

Comment: @xing That was it!

Answer (score 1):

```
                for (int i = 0; i < read - 1; i++) {
                    word[i] = line[i];
                    printf("%x", word[i]);

                }
```

that only print the read characters in hexa, no reason to print the 23/'#'

so if you read *abacus* that prints *616261637573* and none 23

warning if you print word as a string (%s), it doesn't contains a null char to end it

---

A simple way to do what you expect is that :

```
fp = fopen("english_words.txt", "r");
if (fp != NULL) {   
  char w[16];

  while (fscanf(stdin, "%15s", w) == 1)
    printf("%s%s\n", w, "###############" + strlen(w));
}
fclose(fp);
```

The *scanf* reads up to the first 15 characters of a a word, and I check it reads well comparing the result with 1

the form `"###############" + strlen(w)` is a simple way to get a string of '#' whose length is 15 - the length of the read word

Execution :

```
abacus
abacus##########
abalone
abalone#########
abandon
abandon#########
```